# Query MySQL table using current directory name

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to query the database using the current directory name (which is matched to an existing table entry)? I'm trying to create a template page that will pull content based on the current directory it is in.

So the code would look and result something like this:

```
mysql_select_db($table);
$stud_query = "SELECT * from [table] WHERE name = [current url directory];
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($stud_query));
```

So if the url is mysite.com/stack/, the query would return results as if:

```
$stud_query = "SELECT * from [table] WHERE name ="stack";
```

Comment: In the url `mysite.com/stack`, the directory is `/`, the file name is `stack`.

Comment: This makes me imagine a very bad application design.

Comment: @jordanm - Working with PHP and MySQL is new to me, so I'm open to suggestions and recommendations for a better approach/solution.

Comment: I can't give any solid suggestions or recommendations on your solution, as I can only guess what this would be used for. Application design would be outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Whatever you end up doing, be very, *very* careful not to introduce SQL-injection vulnerabilities. For example, white-list the table names as briefly outlined [here](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies) (starting on page 59).

Answer (score 2):

Really you should use mod_rewrite and pass the full route to index for processing/routing by exploding the url into pieces.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Example:

```
<?php 
// http://example.com/controller/action/sub_action

if(isset($_GET['route'])){
    $url_parts = explode('/', $_GET['route']);
    $controller = (isset($url_parts[0]) ? $url_parts[0] : null);
    $action     = (isset($url_parts[1]) ? $url_parts[1] : null);
    $sub_action = (isset($url_parts[2]) ? $url_parts[2] : null);
}

//With this in mind think:
// http://example.com/user/lcherone
// http://example.com/user/logout
// http://example.com/admin/page/add
// Life just got a whole lot easier!!!
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$curDir = array_shift(explode('/', substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1)));
$stud_query = sprintf("SELECT * from %s WHERE name = '%s';", 'table', mysql_real_escape_string($curDir));
```